# How to call a controller method inside the view?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

My problem is when i'm trying to get the best 4 posts who's match the same author name , as you see in the following image :

this is the controller :

[Controller Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nCRJN.png)

and here is the view :

[View code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7RDD.png)

so how i can call the controller method from the view , what's the code will looks like ? and thanks ..

also here is the controller method :

```
public ActionResult SameAuthor(string author)
    {

        var result = db.Books.Where(b => b.Author_name == author).Take(4).ToList();
        return View(result);
    }
```

and the view code (book page , the following code is a part of book page , that show the book details and info , so this code for show under the post details the most 4 post for same author) is :

```
 //DISPLAYING 4 BOOKS FOR SAME AUTHOR   
<div class="well">
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">
                <div class="thumbnail">
                    <img src="/Books/RetrieveImage/@item.Book_id" alt="Generic placeholder thumbnail">
                </div>

                <div class="caption">
                    <h3>@item.Book_name</h3>
                    <p>Some sample text. Some sample text.</p>

                    <p>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">
                            Button
                        </a>

                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" role="button">
                            Button
                        </a>
                    </p>

                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

and thanks

Comment: from which view you want to call the controller code?

Comment: When you access `yourController/SameAuthor?author=somename` , you action method will pass the data to view and you will get the response in your browser. What else are you trying to do ?

Comment: thanks , actually i'm trying to display the view as partial or in same page : localhost/book/19 , so i'll merge the cshtml to the book view , how is that can done ?

Comment: Please include code as *text* in your question, not images.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to show the result of your `SameAuthor` action method inside another view, you may use `Html.Action` helper method to do so.

So in your some other razor view, you can include the below line

```
@Html.Action("SameAuthor","Book",new {author="Author name here"})
```

Comment: Thanks , and i think you are right , but please if you can help me with the view form (code) how it will be , any way i write it in my question so you can just show me how the code will be and thanks , because i'm still new and learning . thanks

Comment: Sorry ! I do not follow what you are saying. As i mentioned in the answer, you can include that line to include the result of that action in your other views. What problem are you having ?

Comment: i have no problem , but i want to know how the cshtml code(Appearance) ,  will be , if you have a look in my question i attached my view code , so iif you can please answer it with my code <div class="well"></div>

Comment: if you still did not got what i meant , i want to handle the result the the view i attached , so you said that i should use the action and it's ok , but also how i can show the result as this image : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/images/customthumbnail_demo.jpg